# php/mysql: sql query for searching in all fields

Tags: php, mysql

i'm having a problem with malformed html syntax in my database (eg. `&amp;` instead of &) - is there a way to run a sql query which will search in all textfields?

thanks

Comment: try to search solution before asking.

Comment: maybe u misunderstood my question - i'm trying to query ALL database fields which contain &amp; not just single fields ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no query syntax more sophisticated than the obvious: searching one column at a time with LIKE.

If your db is not yet very large you could try dumping it out. Then use a text editor to search the resulting dump file.  You may also be able to correct the mistakes with your text editor, and then reload the dumped tables.

But be careful! It may be desirable to store entitized chararacters  ( `&le;  &gt;  &amp; etc` ) instead of their raw text counterparts in your tables.